# How to use mediaplayer and update seekbar in a function that contain custom dialog in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to use mediaplayer in a function that provide dialog with positive and negative answer. when positive answer selected one audio will played, and when negative selected another activity will appear.
I do these and my audio play successfully, but my seekbar couldn't update.

my function name is autoPlayDialog that code of call is this:

```
else {
        if(MainActivity.getBadgeCount() == 0 ){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            autoPlayDialog();
            //Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            //startActivity(i);
        }

    }
```

and then my function code is:

```
private void autoPlayDialog()
{
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song2);
    final SeekBar seekBar;
    final Runnable runnable;
    final Handler handler;
    final ImageView playIcon;

    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.autoseekbar);
    playIcon = findViewById(R.id.autopauseplay);
    handler = new Handler();

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(Splash.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_auto_play,null);
    final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(view)
            .setTitle("new message")
            .setMessage("Do you want to play?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", null) //Set to null. We override the onclick
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .create();

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

            Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    playIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
                    changeSeekbar();

                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            playIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            Button button2 = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

My problem is that this line of code `seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration())` make error and my app closed. autoPlayDialog function is developed in Splash activity and seekbar assigned to another xml file seekbar with this line of code `seekBar = findViewById(R.id.autoseekbar)` that this xml file assigned to view of my dialog: `View view = LayoutInflater.from(Splash.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_auto_play,null);`

Also about playIcon image i have this problem too.

Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: use `view.findViewById(R.id.autoseekbar)` to access seekbar from `activity_auto_play` layout. same for other views

Comment: What is in changeSeekbar method?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i'v done this before :

Comment: it is function with this code: `private void changeSeekbar(){
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    changeSeekbar();
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }`